# JSDocs - How to document implicit parameters and returns

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I am wondering how to document a function like the following:

```
var createInput = function () {
  var type = this.type;

  this.input = {
    val: {},
    type: type
  };
}
```

Technically this.type is an input parameter and this.input is what is returned from this object. How would one document this?

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on the second link by [sapithpocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158868/jsdocs-how-to-document-implicit-parameters-and-returns/41159356?noredirect=1#comment69565123_41159356) seems to show a potential solution.

```
/**
 * The context of the current class.
 * @typedef {Object} ClassContext.
 * @property {string} type - Indicates type. */

/**
 * A method for doing something.
 * @param {...ClassContext} this - a {@link ClassContext} object.
 */
function createInput() { /* Code */ }
```

This is documentation that can be reused for each method the uses object that "owns" the current context, i.e. `this`, and follows the DRY-principle, as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to rewrite the code someway so that it takes arguments and returns some value without any side effects. Easy to document as well!

The question should be more like *how to avoid side-effects*, rather than *how to document side effects*.

```
var createInput = function (type) {
  return {
    val: {},
    type: type
  };
}

this.input = createInput(this.type);
```

Comment: I agree, somewhat, in principle, but we are using a lot of hierarchy in the code with implicitly shared variables. I would basically need to send `context` as a parameter in every function, even though I can access it directly through `this`.

I think the question could be written: How do I document class variables in JSDocs?

Comment: You mean `object` as parameter?

Comment: Check [this](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties) and [this](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)